How to make a ruler to measure "cm"?
As far as I knew, the CSS unit "CM" is only for print media types. 
What if I want to make a ruler that can precisely measure "CM"?
I found using 1cm in stylesheet can be rendered correctly under certain circumstances like the screen is with devicePixelRatio = 1 (on a 1920 x 1080 extended screen) and 50px is pretty close to 1cm on the screens with devicePixelRatio = 2(on a Macbook Air M1 Retina Screen)
A very rough example is like the following:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/unit-cm-x7vvsy?file=/src/App.js
I wondered if there's a solid equation to render exact length as "cm" on screens?

I'm looking for something like under devicePixelRatio=1, 1cm=37px, under devicePixelRatio=2, 1cm=50px, but it seems there's no such usages

Unfortunately, screens in general are not designed to represent these units accurately. Citing the W3C documentation

The relation between the absolute units is as follows: 1in = 2.54cm = 25.4mm = 72pt = 6pc
[sample schema]
The so-called absolute units (cm, mm, in, pt and pc) mean the same in CSS as everywhere else, but only if your output device has a high enough resolution. On a laser printer, 1cm should be exactly 1 centimeter. But on low-resolution devices, such as computer screens, CSS doesn't require that.

If this is a requirement, you could design some kind of calibration procedure, asking your user to adjust a scale parameter until a 10cm ruler is represented accurately enough.

Thanks for saving me great amount of time on tuning this!
